# Cant use SaSS and an option for express

Tags: node.js, express, sass

The old version of express had an option to use sass as the CSS engine for a site. I see now the version I am running (2.5.5) does not offer this up as an option, instead it has vanilla css of stylus.

Can anyone verify that support is still offered.

Comment: This should be [brought to the attention of the developers](https://github.com/visionmedia/express) and has no conclusive answer to be offered here.

Comment: Why has this been down voted? It is a perfectly reasonable question?

Comment: "What gives?" is an opened ended question. You aren't looking for a solution to a problem. It sounds like you're trying to start a discussion about the decision process behind removing a feature of a framework. It would be better if you took that up directly with the developers and opened an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Actually, what gives means does anyone know what is going on. And don't tell me I am not looking for a solution to a problem, why else would I be posting here? I was basing my question on the fact that their tutorial videos show sass as an option. Being new to the eco system does this not seem like a rational question given the confusion? Please revoke the down rating

Comment: If you're going to ask a question like this, you should be more specific. Simply stating "what gives?" implies you want to start a discussion, whether or not that was your intention. Additionally, your bullish attitude when people provide constructive criticism to your "question" doesn't help matters.

Comment: I found this helpful reference for those who cant follow: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071004183931AAz0M3Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this feature has been removed. Use of third party recommended.

Answer (score 1):

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/787) is over 6 months old stating Express doesn't support SASS.

> you have to use something like LESS, sass.js, Stylus, etc. Stylus /
>   LESS both support regular css syntax you can check it out [here](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/)